# Getting a particular value from a function

Tags: python, function, random, return-value, extract

I am trying to extract a particular value from a function which deals with multiple values.

My simplified example:

```
def func(x, y):
    a = ran(0,10)         #creates random integer
    b = ran(0,10)

    return a*x + b*y
    print a*x + b*y
```

So if I want to use the values of `a` and `b` that get created in `func()` in some other function, how would I extract them?

Comment: Is there any reason why they shouldn't be declared outside and used via global, etc instead?

Comment: @Nanashi I am not sure what you mean; I am fairly new to programming.

Comment: If you want to reuse the values, it will be a lot simpler to declare them *outside* the function, unless there's a specific reason you want them created inside the function itself. Check Two-Bit's answer. :)

Comment: @PPG In general, what Nanashi is referring to is called **variable scoping**, and is something you're going to learn a lot about for any language you explore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so much that you need to *extract* them; you just need to save them somewhere.

If this is a top-level function in a module, consider a module variable:

```
import random
rand1 = random.randint(0, 10)
rand2 = random.randint(0, 10)

def f(x, y):
    result = rand1*x + rand2*y
    print result
    return result
```

but these look suspiciously related so perhaps they belong in a class?

```
class YourClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.rand1 = random.randint(0, 10)
        self.rand2 = random.randint(0, 10)

    def your_func_as_a_method(self, x, y):
        result = self.rand1*x + self.rand2*y
        print result
        return result
```

Of course, you could also just make them part of the function's return definition:

```
def f(x, y):
    rand1 = random.randint(0, 10)
    rand2 = random.randint(0, 10)
    result = rand1*x + rand2*y
    print result
    return (result, rand1, rand2)

fxy, a, b = f(x, y)
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Covers everything I needed to know, for now and for later. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to return them:

```
return (a*x + b*y, a, b)
```

and you can call your function as:

```
(result, a, b) = func(x,y)
```

Comment: This answer is also worth thinking about. It is pretty pythonic to return a tuple from a function.